# how i can get the similar character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

welcome

i need to compare between two text in javascript if any character is exist in Main Text and give the position of this character

example :

- please input the first text : Leen
- please input the second text : Meen

i need to create a function to check the all character in the Leen and Meen to get similar character and output must be like this

answer : een

anybody can help me please ?

Comment: _i need to create a function to check_ So where is your code?

Comment: var name ="leen"; // global variable 

            function printstar() 
            {

               for(var c=0; c<name.length; c++)
              {
                  document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML+="*";    
              }
               
            }

            function search_method()
            {
                var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
                alert(input);
                


            }

Comment: Case sensitive?

Comment: @SaifAl-Bashiti Please post this with the question next time, so we have something to start helping you with.

Comment: iam sorry i forget to write my code iam so sorry .. now my code to print star **** and i need to allow user to Guess character if user guess one character i need to change to original text example my text is : JORDAN and user input JaviMara

Comment: @SaifAl-Bashiti Wait a second, that code has nothing to do with the task at hand (unless it's the input/output). Have you tried any code to actually do the task yet?

Comment: con .. i need to change the original text to be like there : J*****

Answer (score 1):

Here is the algorithm I came up:
this works fine with small string, so you don't need to use dp algorithms to improve the performance, if you are trying to find shared substring in two very long strings, then dp is suggested.

```
function a(text1, text2) {
  var maxPossibleLength = text2.length;
  var results = [];
  /*
  var result = {
    targetMatchIndex : 0,
    sourceMatchIndex: 0,
    matchString : ""
  };
  */
  while (maxPossibleLength > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; (i + maxPossibleLength) <= text2.length; i++) {
      var possibleSubstring = text2.substring(i, i + maxPossibleLength);
      var matchIndex = text1.indexOf(possibleSubstring);
      if (matchIndex > 0) {
        results.push({
          targetMatchIndex: matchIndex,
          sourceMatchIndex: i,
          matchString: possibleSubstring
        })
      }
    }
    //match max substring only
    if(results.length > 0) {
      break;
    }
    maxPossibleLength--;
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(a("13423323", "a23b"))
```

Comment: thanks please can you edit the code to make it Print the answer in html code ?

Comment: Are you going to do ANY of this assignment by yourself?

Comment: @SaifAl-Bashiti If you can't do that, we shouldn't be doing it for you. You have to actually learn how to code somehow.